# Implicit conversions in Idris 2?

Tags: implicit-conversion, idris

Are implicit conversions still available in Idris 2? This Idris 1 code

```
data Foo : Type -> Type where
  MkFoo : t -> Foo t

public export implicit
IntFoo : Int -> Foo Int
IntFoo = MkFoo
```

now fails to compile in Idris 2 with

```
Error: Parse error at line 95:1:
Couldn't parse declaration (next
tokens: [public, export, implicit, identifier IntFoo, symbol :, identifier Int, symbol ->, identifier Foo, identifier Int, identifier IntFoo])
```

Moving `implicit` doesn't fix it, and it compiles fine if I remove `implicit`.

Btw I looked in the docs for updating from 1 to 2 but can't see anything about this. If you know where to look, a link would also be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit conversions are not supported in Idris 2. [I believe their exclusion is deliberate](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/issues/1003#issuecomment-771223134).

Comment: Thanks. Do you remember how you found this out?

Comment: @joel I asked on the Slack #idris on fpchat-invite.herokuapp.com